# When using Object.create() how do you reference Object keys withing other object keys

Tags: javascript, event-handling, object-create

I'm trying to learn Object.create by making a contrived calculator module.  I've tried `bind` I've tried removing `this`, but no results.

**QUESTION:**

**How do you reference a property of an object within another property of an element like you would with a class.** Or is my example not a very good pattern? If so, how *should* I structure my Calculator Object to afford event listeners on `creation`?

**Calculator.js**

```
const Calculator = {
  inputArr: [],
  init: (selector)=> {
    const el = document.querySelector(selector);
    el.addEventListener('click', this.pushValue); // this wont work.
    return this;
  },
  pushValue: (e) => {
    let val = e.target.value;
    if(val){
      this.inputArr.push(val);
      console.log(e.target, this.inputArr); // this wouldn't work.
    }
  }
};

const adder = Object.create(Calculator).init('#calc');
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="calc">
  <button class="btns" value="1">1</button>
  <button class="btns" value="2">2</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in that code is you've used arrow functions, but closing over the wrong `this`. Arrow functions close over the `this` where they're defined, rather than having it set when they're called. In your case, it's closing over the `this` at global scope.

If you make `init` and `pushValue` normal functions and call them via references to the object created via `Object.create`, they'll get called with the correct `this`:

```
const Calculator = {
  inputArr: [],
  init: function(selector) {                                 // ****
    const el = document.querySelector(selector);
    el.addEventListener('click', this.pushValue.bind(this)); // ****
    return this;
  },
  pushValue: function(e) {                                   // ****
    let val = e.target.value;
    if(val){
      this.inputArr.push(val);
      console.log(e.target, this.inputArr);
    }
  }
};

const adder = Object.create(Calculator).init('#calc');
```

You do need to `bind` the call to `pushValue` from the event listener (otherwise, `this` will refer to the element). Or alternately, wrap it in an arrow:

```
el.addEventListener('click', e => this.pushValue(e));
```

Working example using the arrow wrapper on `this.pushValue`:

```js
const Calculator = {
  inputArr: [],
  init: function(selector) { // ****
    const el = document.querySelector(selector);
    el.addEventListener('click', e => this.pushValue(e)); // ****
    return this;
  },
  pushValue: function(e) { // ****
    let val = e.target.value;
    if (val) {
      this.inputArr.push(val);
      console.log(e.target, this.inputArr);
    }
  }
};

const adder = Object.create(Calculator).init('#calc');
```

```html
<div id="calc">
  <button class="btns" value="1">1</button>
  <button class="btns" value="2">2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahh such simple.  damn gotcha of fat arrows.